# Emailing a bunch of users selected from a user reference field

Tags: 7, rules, notifications, users

I have a node that lets me select multiple users in a user reference field. I also have a rules setup to email the author when someone makes a comment on that node.

Now, how do I also email the users I selected in the user reference field when someone makes a comment? Would rules work in this scenario or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add another "Send email" action to your rule, but place it inside a Rules loop so it can iterate over the multiple values in the user reference field. You may need to first add an "Entity has field" condition to get access to these values.

Comment: thanks that works. this is how it looks for those wondering: http://prntscr.com/84wq23

Comment: Happy to help. :) Rules can be tricky. It would be great if you could select this as the correct answer so others will see that it has been answered. Cheers -

Comment: @duckx : please consider marking this question as accepted (also as per your ***thanks that works***). That way it won't show up anymore in the [unanswered questions](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/unanswered) either. BTW: by doing so, you'll get a tine (+2) bonus also ...